# jquery loaded with ajax works in localhost but not on server

Tags: jquery

I have this code to load jquery content inside a div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#agile").click(function(event) {
    $("#main").load("agile.php #container").hide().fadeIn(2000);
    $.getScript("js/vTabs.js");
    });

    $("#apollo").click(function(event) {
    $("#main").load("apollo.php #container").hide().fadeIn(2000);
    $.getScript("js/vTabs.js");
    });

    $("#corner").click(function(event) {
    $("#main").load("corner.php #container").hide().fadeIn(2000);
    $.getScript("js/vTabs.js");
    });

});
```

I use the "$.getScript("js/vTabs.js);" to load the jQuery but this only works on local.  On the server the content is displayed with no styles, which is part of what the .js does.  I see on Firebug that the .js is being requested but still the styles it links to won't display.

I appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it :)  Changed .getScript for .bind.

This:

```
$("#agile").click(function(event) {
$("#main").load("agile.php #container").hide().fadeIn(2000);
$.getScript("js/vTabs.js");
});
```

for:

```
$("#agile").bind("click", function(){
$("#main").load("agile.php #container", function(){
$('#vtabs5').jVertTabs();
});
});
```

Of course, this applies to my particular example but it might guide someone else :)